# (C++) openmp leading to segmentation fault

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm new to using OpenMP on C++ and facing some issues with it:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

using namespace std;
using boost::multiprecision::cpp_int;

// generates prime numbers under n
vector<int> generatePrime(int n) {
  vector<int> primes;
  for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    bool isPrime = true;
    for (int j = 0; j < primes.size(); j++) {
      if (i % primes[j] == 0) {
        isPrime = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (isPrime) {
      primes.push_back(i);
    }
  }
  return primes;
}

// checks if an integer is a prime number
bool chkPrime(vector<int> vec, vector<int> ref) {
  for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
    if (find(ref.begin(), ref.end(), vec[i]) == ref.end()) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

int main() {
  vector<int> primes = generatePrime(100);
  vector<cpp_int> row(1, 1);
  int maxAlleles = 1000;
  vector<vector<int>> rowPrime;
  for (int alleles = 1; alleles <= maxAlleles; alleles++) {
    vector<cpp_int> row1 = row;
    row1.push_back(0);
    row1.push_back(0);
    vector<cpp_int> row2 = row1;
    vector<cpp_int> row3 = row1;
    vector<cpp_int> rowFinal;
    rotate(row2.begin(), row2.end() - 1, row2.end());
    rotate(row3.begin(), row3.end() - 2, row3.end());

    for (int i = 0; i < row1.size(); i++) {
      // making the next row of the trinomial triangle
      rowFinal.push_back(row1[i] + row2[i] + row3[i]);
    }
    row = rowFinal;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    // for each number in the row, we will make the number into a string and divide it by 2 letters
    // and put it into a vector (splitTwo), starting from the beginning of the string
    for (int num = 0; num < row.size(); num++) {
      string item = to_string(row[num]);
      vector<int> splitTwo;
      int i = 0;

      if (item.length() % 2 == 0) {
        while (i <= item.length() - 2) {
          splitTwo.push_back(stoi(item.substr(i, 2)));
          i += 2;
        }
      }

      else {
        if (item.length() > 2) {
          while (i <= item.length() - 3) {
            splitTwo.push_back(stoi(item.substr(i, 2)));
            i += 2;
          }
        }
        int last_letter = item[item.length() - 1] - '0';
        splitTwo.push_back(last_letter);
      }

      // we are going to push back splitTwo in rowPrime if all items in splitTwo are prime numbers
      if (chkPrime(splitTwo, primes) == true) {
        splitTwo.push_back(alleles);
        splitTwo.push_back(num);
        rowPrime.push_back(splitTwo);
      }
    }
  }
  vector<int> sum;
  for (int k = 0; k < rowPrime.size(); k++) {
    sum.push_back(
      accumulate(begin(rowPrime[k]), end(rowPrime[k]) - 2, 0, plus<int>()));
  }

  int idx = distance(begin(sum), max_element(begin(sum), end(sum)));
  for (int &i : rowPrime[idx]) {
    cout << i << ' ';
  }
  cout << sum[idx] << ' ' << rowPrime.size();
  return 0;
}
```

When I use `pragma omp parallel for` on the code above and make an executable file, it leads to different results each time I execute the code: either 1) outputs the answer properly, or 2) gives a `segmentation fault` error, or 3) gives a `Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x7fd0ef904088: probably modified after being freed. Corrupt value: 0x0 malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug` error. When I remove `pragma omp parallel for` it does not give me these errors. Any suggestions?

Comment: `push_back` is not threadsafe, so `rowPrime.push_back(splitTwo);` line causes problem. You can 1) use a critical section, 2) use a user-defined reduction to protect it.

Comment: Looks like this was the problem. Adding `#pragma omp critical` on top of `rowPrime.push_back(splitTwo);` addresses the issue.

Comment: There are several performance issues in this code making it slow and preventing it to scale well on many platforms. One big issue is the allocations caused by using massively vectors and strings. Another issue is the linear search in a vector in a loop: you can certainly use a merge since one of the vector is sorted and the other can be, or to use a fast hash table (possibly even a bloom filter for that). Regarding your needs, `stoi` may not be very efficient.